# How to clean up date field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

http://postimg.org/image/s336si4pv/

I have a table of horse racing information with many jockeys, horses, the dates that they've raced on and other non essential information to this problem (in this table, I've selected only one jockey for demonstration). I want to first, clean up the date field, and create a column that finds the difference between the earliest day that the jockey has raced on and the last day he has raced in the table (ie how long he has been racing for).

Thank you,

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE(fieldname,'%e%b%y');` for the cleanup, then it becomes a simple query.

Comment: Why is the date in this 'format' to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would add a new column to your table.
Call it `corrected_date` or something like that with type `date`.

Next I'd set all values of corrected_date to `NULL`

`UPDATE tablename SET corrected_date NULL;`

Convert datestring to date and assign it to `corrected_date`

`UPDATE tablename SET corrected_date = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(prevdates, ' ', 1), '%e%b%y) WHERE a_id = a_i AND prevdates <> '---';`

Check if the `SUBSTRING_INDEX(prevdates, ' ', 1)` part works for getting only the date.
Check if the `STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(prevdates, ' ', 1), '%e%b%y)`part converts you date correctly.